# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter still showing all items. Should not show any

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to check if there invites ending with email address, and show uids. Somehow it output all data, as if there were no filtering and ordering.

Here is json data.

```
"invites" : {
  "4u60kmvvO9TwzBrLpP5SG4ICU9r1_test5%2E@test%2Etest" : {
    "cost" : "2",
  },
  "4u60kmvvO9TwzBrLpP5SG4ICU9r1_test4@test%2Etest" : {
    "costs" : "0"
  },
  "UQW5VEAojMOyB2WGTU9aTPUBepg1_test6%2E@test%2Etest" : {
    "costs" : "0"      
  }
}
```

I want to set FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Here is adapter.

```
 mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, UserHolder>(
      Event.class, 
      R.layout.layout, 
      UserHolder.class, 
      ref.child("invites").orderByKey().endAt(encodeAsFirebaseKey(email))
 ) {}
```

Why I'm getting all three items, when I test with test@test.test email? It seems that I've read documentation and it should work. Any ideas?

**Update**.

```
 private String encodeAsFirebaseKey(String string) {
    return string.replace(".", "%2E");
}
```

It returns test@test%2Etest.

```
     protected void populateViewHolder(final UserHolder viewHolder, Event model, final int position) {
     final String key = this.getRef(position).getKey().split("_")[0];
            viewHolder.setName(key);     
            }
```

Comment: That depends on the value that `encodeAsFirebaseKey(email)` returns. Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value instead of that call?

Comment: It returns test@test%2Etest. Should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to be confusing how `endAt()` works. It matches all strings, ending at the one that starts with the argument you pass. It does **not** match strings ending with the argument you pass.

So `endAt("4u60kmvvO9TwzBrLpP5SG4ICU9r1_test4@test%2Etest")` matches:

```
"4u60kmvvO9TwzBrLpP5SG4ICU9r1_test5%2E@test%2Etest" : {
  "cost" : "2",
},
"4u60kmvvO9TwzBrLpP5SG4ICU9r1_test4@test%2Etest" : {
  "costs" : "0"
},
```

But `endAt("test@test%2Etest")` returns nothing, because no key starts with that.

Comment: It seems that data structure should be changed to be able to filter by child. This is weired to, cause of double use of email as a part of key and as child.